# Extra std::map::contains call vs handling an exception?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, stdmap

What is more efficient in c++?

```
if (my_map.contains(my_key)) return my_map.at(my_key);
```

or

```
try { return my_map.at(my_key); } catch (std::out_of_range e) { ... }
```

?

Comment: What are the odds that an exception will happen? Once a year, or 9 times out of 10? Exceptions are expensive, if they happen.

Comment: Please define "more efficient" in objective terms, and include in your edit information about your compiler as well as the hardware specs of the machine that will be running this. Or better yet, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use [`std::map<>::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

```cpp
if (auto it = my_map.find(my_key); it != my_map.end()) return *it;
```

Which avoids the double lookup for `contains` followed by `at` and the expensive exception handling for if `at` throws